# How to set UILabel to wrap UIButton via AutoLayouts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

- I have an UILabel located in the left (use leading constraint)
- and I have UIButton located on the right side (use trailing constraint to locate in on the right side).
- UILabel has dynamic text with several rows/lines.
- Application is universal

I use following constraints (see screenshot):

- leading constraint for label to view (on the left)
- trailing constraint for button to view (on the right)
- and I use trailing constraint for label to button (leading)

In that case button is shifted out of the screen by label.

So, how to set label to wrap button using autolayouts/constraint?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand clearly your question

Comment: you need to extend the frame of your uilabel or make the label trailing to 10pts to button. If you look at the current constraint ,the trailing for your butotn should be more than 70/80.

Comment: updated question with updated screenshot

Comment: the trailing for the label is too much, so it pushes the buton aside. You should give the trailing constraint 10 to the label, and this trailing of label should be given to the button but not to the view @Bogdan

Comment: I actually do this way, label has trailing not to the view, but to the button: "label.trailing = button.leading + 10"

Comment: what does it mean, that trailing for button should be more than 70/80? (I don't have such layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding additional constraint for the button - fixed width.

Now it works

[image]